# Copy prediction model in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

In my predictive python code

I use the sklearn prediction model (KNN, RandomForest, LinearRegression, etc)

in a loop as the loop try to find the best hyper-param optimization.

once I find the best parameters I want to take a copy of the **trained** model

How can I do that?

```
for k in range(1,10):
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k)
    ...
    #some code to fit and train the model here and find the accuracy
    ...
    if accuracy > top_accuracy:
         top_accuracy = accuracy
         top_knn = knn <==== ?


# code to fit top_knn with a new test dataset
```

does this copy the trained model with the trained, is there any way I can make sure that my model has trained data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scikit-learn` contains components for hyperparameter tuning (cf. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html). Example code is [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_grid_search_digits.html). The best model found during a search can be accessed via `clf.best_estimator_`.

Comment: I am using existing library and I still have to provide the value of K in the KNN model

Comment: I've updated my answer with a link to sklearn's example code.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using sklearn? Each time you train it, the KNN object retains the most recent fitting function. If you want to document whether the new fit performs better than the last, I would just create a new class and assign the model object to it:

```
class foo:
    __init__(self,model,accuracy):
        self.current = model
        self.accuracy = accuracy

if accuracy > foo.accuracy:
    foo.current = model
```

Comment: will it be trained?